# How can I buy a hat with my gold?

Tags: moomoo.io

I was playing in [moomoo.io](/questions/tagged/moomoo.io) as normal when I came across a player with a red hat:

[image]

Then, I found some more people with the hat:

[image]

Can I get that hat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get that hat **provided you have enough gold**.

First, click the shop icon to the left of the people icon for tribes and the leaderboard.

[image: Shop icon with arrow pointing to it]

You can scroll through the pop-up and when you want to buy a hat, click the buy button on that hat's row. Each hat will cost different amounts of gold, so if you don't have enough gold you won't get that hat.

[image: Hats pop-up]

Some hats give you special traits, such as the winter hat. These traits can be shown when you hover over a hat's row in the menu:

[image: Winter hat information on hover]

Once you're done with the shop for hats, press <kbd>esc</kbd> or click the shop icon once more.